# Taylor Expansion of the scale factor in terms of redshift

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

I was reading about the Taylor expansion of the scale factor from [visser,2004](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0309109)

He writes:

$$ \frac{a(t)}{a_0} = 1 +H_0 (t -t_0) - \frac{q_0}{2} {H_0}^{2}(t-t_0)^2  + \frac{j_0}{3 !} {H_0}^{3}(t-t_0)^3  + \\  + \frac{s_0}{4 !} {H_0}^{4}(t-t_0)^4  + \frac{l_0}{5!} {H_0}^{5}(t-t_0)^5  + \mathcal{O}(t- t_0)^6
$$

where $q,j$ and $s$ are the deceleration, the jerk and the snak parameters. But I would like to see it expanded in terms of the redshift $z$. I suppose I should use the fact that:

$$a(t) = \frac{1}{1+z} \ ,$$

but how do I transform the dependence from $t$ to $z$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there.

$$
\frac{a(t)}{a(t_0)} = (1+z)^{-1} = 1-z+z^2-z^3 + \cdots
$$

which converges for $z<1$.

Comment: $(1+z)^{-1} $ will converge for any positive value of $z$

Comment: No, the radius of convergence is $1$.